# Ajax Works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

Everything works well in firefox, all the data return a value, but on chrome, they are all undefined. 
I tried to empty my function with only a simple string return ex. 'asd' and this still return Undefined.
Working on wordpress.

```
$('.vote-synergy-up, .vote-synergy-down').click(function(){
    var data_synergy = $(this).parent('.vote-synergy-container').attr('data-synergy'); /*PK SYNERGY*/
    var VoteType = '';
    var OtherVoteType = '';

    if ($(this).hasClass('vote-synergy-up')){
        VoteType = 'Up';
        OtherVoteType = 'Down';
    }

    if ($(this).hasClass('vote-synergy-down')){
        VoteType = 'Down';
        OtherVoteType = 'Up';
    }

    // This does the ajax request
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: omvp_ajax.ajax_url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'action':'synergy_vote',
            'pk_Synergy' : data_synergy,
            'VoteType' : VoteType
        },
        success:function(data) {
            alert(data.Test)
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){

            alert('An error as occured');
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });  
});
```

Here is my function

```
function synergy_vote() {

if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'Test'=>'ASD'
            )
    );
}
```

}

Comment: What is being logged if you console.log(data) in the success callback function?

Comment: Ok first, I didn't know that I had to login, now it's working.
Can you explain me why? Seems that my friend still can't vote even if he is logged in.

Comment: Where is `omvp_ajax.ajax_url` defined ?

Comment: In the same file as the function, the function.php from wordpress  wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'omvp_ajax', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

Answer (score 1):

Replaced

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_synergy_vote', 'synergy_vote' ); // It called from the back end
```

With

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_synergy_vote', 'synergy_vote' );    // If called from front end
```

Comment: Let me ask you something, were you logged in as an admin in Firefox, but not in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the JSON that's returned from the server.

```
success:function(data) {
    var d = $.parseJSON(data);
    alert(d.Test);
},
```

Comment: Send an error. SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data